# SQL Loop through records in a table

Tags: sql, loops, cursor, case

I have a table called master, the primary key is account_num. Each account number has an account_type (single character). I need to do the following:

1. find all accounts with a type of A or B.
2. store that account number in a new table called year_end_close along with a time stamp of when that transaction takes place
3. set all accounts in master with a type of A to C, and all accounts with a type of B to D

What's the best way to handle this in SQL? While loop? Case statement? Cursor? Any help is appreciated. The table has about 17,000 rows.

Comment: You can do it with 2 queries.  An insert and an update.

Comment: Well, 3 queries if you haven't created the table yet.

Comment: My familiarity with SQL scripting is very limited - I know how I would do it in other languages but my uncertainty lies in how to ensure that I'm looking at each record in the table and performing the action for each of those records - if that makes sense.

Comment: What's your database? SQL Server? Oracle? MySQL?

Comment: Database is SQL server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't need to use a cursor/loop to do something like this. When writing SQL, always try to look for a set-based solution first. I would recommend a `CASE` statement, which was one of the options you mentioned.

Try this:

```
BEGIN TRAN;

SELECT account_num, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
INTO year_end_close
FROM dbo.master
WHERE account_type IN ('a','b');

UPDATE dbo.master
SET account_type = CASE account_type
                     WHEN 'a' THEN 'c'
                     WHEN 'b' THEN 'd'
                     ELSE account_type
                     END
WHERE account_type IN ('a','b');

COMMIT TRAN;
```

Comment: This is basically the way I'd go, though I would pick nits and use ANSI `current_timestamp` instead of proprietary `getdate()`, and apply the same where clause to both the select and the update.

Comment: @TimLehner you're right, good points. I usually use `current_timestamp` myself; I just thought `getdate()` would be easier to follow for someone not used to SQL, and I didn't know `current_timestamp` was the ANSI standard. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Good advice on set-based logic.  SELECT... INTO... is proprietary syntax as well.  If you want to be strict ANSI, use a separate CREATE TABLE and INSERT... SELECT...  Also, you might want to filter the for rows that exist in year_end_close.  Depending on activity and isolation level, you could update rows that were inserted or updated after your insert to year_end_close.

Comment: Thanks so much - this seems to do just what I need!

Answer (score 2):

Are you searching for something like this? (Replace the 'PRINT' statements for your actual SQL statements)

```
DECLARE @MasterTable TABLE
(
  account_num int,
  account_type varchar(1)
)
INSERT INTO @MasterTable VALUES (1, 'A')
INSERT INTO @MasterTable VALUES (2, 'A')
INSERT INTO @MasterTable VALUES (3, 'B')
INSERT INTO @MasterTable VALUES (4, 'B')
INSERT INTO @MasterTable VALUES (5, 'C')
INSERT INTO @MasterTable VALUES (6, 'C')

DECLARE @account_num int
DECLARE @account_type varchar(1)
DECLARE @switch_type varchar(1)

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR  
SELECT account_num, account_type 
FROM @MasterTable
WHERE account_type IN ('A', 'B')  

OPEN db_cursor   
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @account_num, @account_type  

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN   
    IF @account_type = 'A'
        SET @switch_type = 'C'
    ELSE
        SET @switch_type = 'D'

    PRINT 'INSERT year_end_close (account_num, timestampfield) VALUES (' + CAST(@account_num AS VARCHAR) + ', GETDATE())'
    PRINT 'UPDATE @MasterTable SET account_type = ' + @switch_type + ' WHERE account_num = ' + CAST(@account_num AS VARCHAR)
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @account_num, @account_type   
END   

CLOSE db_cursor   
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```